# Probability of collision in S-box

Tags: cryptography

I'm trying to understand a cryptanalysis of the Blowfish cipher, and I need to calculate the probability of collision in the cipher's S-boxes. Basically an S-box is a list of 256 semi-random 32-bit numbers. We can assume that the values are random for convenience. I need to know how I calculate the probability that

$$
S(a) = S(a')
$$$$
a \neq a'
$$

where **a** and **a'** are positions in the S-box.

Comment: no you should accept my answer and post a new question instead of post facto editing to make my answer wrong..

Comment: @caveman Fair enough. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332150/probability-of-a-characteristic-in-blowfish)'s the new question.

Comment: thanks - welcome to the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it for some time it seems the problem is trivial: The probability is just $\frac{1}{2^{32}}$.

If we're modelling S boxes as random functions from 8 bit numbers (but this doesn't even matter) to 32 bit numbers, then the chance of $a'$ (a number distinct from $a$) having the same $S$ value (which is just a random 32 bit number) as $a$ is just $\frac{1}{2^{32}}$.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. Makes me wonder if I missinterpreted the analysis though, since they gave another value there. I'll add some information to the question.

Comment: @Psyberion, yeah I'm sure this is useless in the analysis.